# Using wildcards in word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I have created a template in Word 2007 with several fields that I want the users to be able to quickly find and edit.  I have indicated those fields like so:  [change this].

I want to create a macro which will find all words beginning with "[" and ending with "]" and highlight them.

My macro so far finds all words that start with "[" and highlights them.  I just can't figure out how to have it highlight the rest of the word including "]".

I reviewed the rules for wildcards here http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm and thought I could use something like this:  <[]> but it never finds anything.

I would appreciate some help!  Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
Sub HighlightAllItems()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim searchText As String

searchText = "["

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
With myRange.Find
.MatchWildcards = True
.Text = searchText
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.Highlight = True
.Replacement.Text = searchText
.Forward = True
.Format = True
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, post the code you already have for finding and highlighting "[".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this search pattern: `\[<*>\]`

Comment: Thanks, that got me closer!  That works in the Find/Replace dialog box but not in the macro.  I get an error The Replace With text contains a group number which is out of range.